# copperhead python

Tags: python, c++, массивы, arraylist

Как передать одномерный массив в функцию с библиотекой copperhead python. Вот код который есть сейчас

```
func_cpp = '''
float mult9(float* a, float* b, int size)
{
    float value = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        value += a[i] * b[i];
    }
    return value;
}
'''
multiply = cpp.generate('mult9', 'float(float*, float*, int)', func_cpp)
```

Выдаёт вот эту ошибку ещё при компиляции: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'python_type' referenced before assignment

Comment: так а что за python_type переменная в вашем питоновском коде?

Comment: Нет, это переменная из библиотеки copperhead, из модуля code_generator

Comment: Похоже это ошибка означает что я не правильно инициализирую функцию тут `multiply = cpp.generate('mult12', 'float(float*, float*, int)', func_cpp)` , не правильные типы данных в неё закидываю, но я нигде не могу найти как это правильно делать, и вообще не уверен в этом